# blender script to read .OBJ file

Tags: scripting, objects, blender-internal-render-engine, makehuman

Using Blender script, I need to read human body from an .obj file and identify the human parts of it respectively.

The following is the script used to read the .obj file:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.import_obj(filepath="d://test.obj")
```

The error I am getting is "python script fail"

Comment: Is this really the complete script? I would put the bpy.ops stuff into a class. The interesting part of the error message would be the part where it tells you what exactly fails. Another thing that jumps into my eyes is the useage of backslashes instead of slashes. Windows uses slashes in file paths.

Comment: The operator call is `bpy.ops.scene.import_obj(...)`