# Importing of .mhx2 ( or .obj) files possible with python script?

Tags: python, scripting, import

Does anybody now how to import a mhx2 human model into blender using python script? I alread was looking it up in the web but was not possible to find anything. The closest I got: [blender script to import .obj file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64560/blender-script-to-read-obj-file)

Hopefully someone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following script to import mhx2 files into blender.

```
bpy.ops.import_scene.makehuman_mhx2(filepath="~/Desktop/myfile.mhx2")
```

make sure before running the script you have activated the makehuman import runtime addon in your blender.